# MySQL: Group PlayerUID, Show total kills and latest coordinates of alive character

Tags: mysql

I've been wrestling with this for a while now and haven't found a solution.

I have a MySQL database table which contains game character data, with the following columns:

- **CharacterID:** Once the player dies, he gets new character, which adds a new entry.
- **PlayerUID:** Unique for each player. Need to group by that.
- **KillsZ:** Shows how many kill each character has had.
- **Worldspace:** The position of the character.
- **Alive:** Is the character alive or dead?

So I need an SQL query that returns the total kills for a player and the coordinates of their current character. How could I do this?

This is what I think should be:

```
SELECT CharacterID, PlayerUID, sum(KillsZ), Worldspace, alive
FROM character_data
WHERE Worldspace IN (SELECT Worldspace FROM character_data WHERE alive = 1)
GROUP BY PlayerUID
ORDER BY sum(KillsZ) DESC;
```

Output: (11 top rows)

```
"CharacterID"   "PlayerUID" "sum(KillsZ)"   "Worldspace"    "alive"
"924"   "76561198042033373" "88"    "[128,[8438.99,3093.65,7.408]]" "1"
"509"   "76561198117519944" "78"    "[234,[4284.56,6222.69,-4.425e-04]]"    "1"
"1360"  "76561198046918433" "63"    "[194,[8735.35,5139.39,16.179]]"    "1"
"1457"  "76561197988106961" "46"    "[146,[8740.07,5089.61,0.278]]" "1"
"606"   "76561198050960639" "40"    "[317,[4523.15,1815.6,0.889]]"  "1"
"1413"  "76561198053078285" "37"    "[303,[5908.08,2024.8,0.002]]"  "1"
"597"   "76561198118406618" "36"    "[338,[4433.23,1619.99,0.001]]" "1"
"99"    "76561197988519309" "32"    "[]"    "0"
"1384"  "76561198088203111" "31"    "[205,[2334.34,8904.73,0.001]]" "1"
"375"   "76561197965753706" "30"    "[307,[3962.21,7522.75,7.299]]" "1"
"1364"  "76561198013225036" "28"    "[195,[8452.11,3093.67,0.198]]" "1"
```

And here is the query without:

```
SELECT CharacterID, PlayerUID, sum(KillsZ), Worldspace, alive
FROM character_data
GROUP BY PlayerUID
ORDER BY sum(KillsZ) DESC;
```

Which outputs: (11 top rows)

```
"CharacterID"   "PlayerUID" "sum(KillsZ)"   "Worldspace"    "alive"
"14"    "76561198034271930" "982"   "[96,[6462.44,3728.73,0]]"  "0"
"3" "76561198053078285" "754"   "[106,[6024.94,1215.49,0]]" "0"
"12"    "76561197988519309" "427"   "[147,[2387.11,4747.59,0.002]]" "0"
"48"    "76561198022644097" "383"   "[11,[7879.52,1695.43,3.368]]"  "0"
"636"   "76561198055683105" "344"   "[184,[5063.51,3356.11,0.001]]" "0"
"635"   "76561198084556053" "312"   "[311,[8730.96,5077.45,0.001]]" "0"
"855"   "76561198096335334" "262"   "[191,[7116.15,2484.91,0]]" "0"
"560"   "76561198082709294" "247"   "[234,[1967.64,5471.63,0.002]]" "0"
"8" "76561198154755873" "217"   "[99,[5438.96,3317.55,0.002]]"  "0"
"96"    "76561197961156126" "206"   "[117,[2597.8,3383.29,0.876]]"  "0"
"806"   "76561198007739284" "180"   "[312,[6502.08,3744.86,0.003]]" "0"
```

You can see that total kills are different.

Comment: It's somehow messing with total kills. Some of the characters Kills wont be in total as they should be.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Should you be using `SUM(killsz)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `GROUP BY` your result set, standard SQL requires using aggregate functions with any of the columns that are not in your `GROUP BY` clause. This is because there are multiple rows corresponding to each group, with different (or potentially different) values in the non-grouping columns. Which of these values does your query refer to? Other DBMS will not process an ambiguous query like the one in your question, but [MySQL allows you to do this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) under the assumption that you will only ever do it when all of the possible values in the non-grouping columns are constant within a group.

It sounds like you want the total kills *of all characters associated with the player*, which is as easy as summing the `KillsZ` column over each group:

```
SELECT
  PlayerUID,
  SUM(KillsZ) AS TotalKills
FROM character_data
GROUP BY PlayerUID;
```

To add the coordinates of the currently-alive character, you could use a `CASE` expression to nullify the coordinates in each row corresponding to a dead character, and then use the aggregate function `MAX` to take the single value that remains:

```
SELECT
  PlayerUID,
  SUM(KillsZ) AS Total_Kills,
  MAX(CASE WHEN alive = 1 THEN Worldspace END) AS Current_Coordinates
FROM character_data
GROUP BY PlayerUID;
```

This is a simple query that makes only one pass over the data and could be satisfied by an appropriate covering index (if necessary for performance). In comparison, the solution that suggests outer joining your table to itself is fairly complex but could be satisfied by smaller indexes, if that's important. One important difference between the two solutions is that mine will show you players who have only dead characters, while the other as currently written will not.

This relies on the important assumption that only one row in any group will have `alive = 1` at any given time. You might want to consider enforcing this constraint within the database. As long as a player can only have at most one character alive in the database, you'll get the same result from either `MAX` or `MIN` and can use either one. If your coordinates value is numeric, you could even use `SUM`, though I think that would be a bit misleading (and it wouldn't work if your coordinates are stored as a CHAR type).

In MySQL you can replace this simple `CASE` expression with `IF(alive = 1, Worldspace, NULL)` but since this is less portable and not significantly less verbose, I would recommend sticking with `CASE` which is part of the SQL standard.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that I got it working just how I wanted with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's recreate your table using SQLite:

```
sqlite> create table characters(playerid integer, kills integer, x integer, y integer, alive integer);
sqlite> insert into characters values(1, 10, 20, 40, 0);
sqlite> insert into characters values(1, 20, 30, 40, 0);
sqlite> insert into characters values(2, 99, 33, 66, 1);
sqlite> insert into characters values(1, 11, 22, 33, 1);
```

**NOTE:** SQLite tables have an implict `rowid` column, which we're going to use as the `characterid` field.

You can get the coordinates of the current "alive" characters pretty easily:

```
sqlite> SELECT playerid, x, y FROM characters WHERE alive = 1; 
2|33|66
1|22|33
```

It's also rather straightforward to get the total number of kills:

```
sqlite> SELECT playerid, SUM(kills) FROM characters GROUP BY playerid;
1|41
2|99
```

Given the above, it should simply be a case of joining these two sets of results together:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM (SELECT playerid, x, y FROM characters WHERE alive = 1) AS A LEFT JOIN (SELECT playerid, SUM(kills) FROM characters GROUP BY playerid) AS B ON A.playerid = B.playerid;
2|33|66|2|99
1|22|33|1|41
```